# CURSOR and LOOP don't work correctly on Oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem with my PL-SQL script on Oracle database. That's not work correctly. I've heard one statement is useless. I can't figure out which one.

```
DECLARE
CURSOR emp_cur IS
SELECT ename, deptno, empno
FROM emp
WHERE sal <
2500;
emp_rec emp_cur%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
FOR emp_rec IN emp_cur
LOOP
give_raise (emp_rec.empno, 10000);
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: `emp_rec emp_cur%ROWTYPE;` is not needed.. as `FOR LOOP` variable _DONOT_ required to be declared! The statement after `IN` decides the datatype(Record/Primitive)

Comment: why not simply run `update emp set sal = sal + 10000 where sal < 2055`. **Much** more efficient that the row-by-row based approach

Answer (score 0):

you could try this way. It is not necessary declare explicity the cursor if you only use it as an iterator in a for loop. I think the same as OracleUser2 about the explicit  declaration of emp_rec.

```
DECLARE

BEGIN
  FOR emp_rec IN (select ename, deptno, empno from emp where sal < 2500)
  LOOP
      give_raise (emp_rec.empno, 10000);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Thanks
Regards